# How to optimize size of big amount of data? Am I approaching this correctly?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, bigdata, database

**Introduction**

Let's assume that I have 1000 sensors. Each sensor sends measurements to my API every 1 minute. This API simply puts the values into my database.

There will be:

- Static sensors - they're in one location and never moves.
- Dynamic sensors - their location can be changed every measurement.

Some sensors measure air quality, humidity, temperature and pressure and some sensors measure only air quality. And maybe in the future there will be sensors which I don't know what they will measure yet.

**Additional information**

After gathering the data I want to represent them as a web heatmap. So, I probably want to be able to query database in the way that it will return the measurements in selected area.

You can simply calculate that I will have 43.2M requests every month - which is about 1.4 GB. So the optimization of a size of the data which will be stored here would be appreciated.

**I thought about making 3 tables:**

[image: database tables]

**How am I going to deal with it?**

There are 2 different tables - am_static_measurements and am_dynamic_measurements since there will be much more static sensors than dynamic (as for now, I believe) and I don't want to waste storage for the same localization data.

If any sensor won't have (for example) pressure measurement, I will simply put NULL to the table and if some sensors will collect any other data which I didn't predict, I will just add another column to the table.

**Questions**

Is it good approach? Is relational database (MySQL) good for this? Any advises? Should I consolidate both am_static_measurements and am_dynamic_measurements into one table in order to have larger size of the stored data but easier requests?

Comment: "I will just add another column to the table" - this will be very unpleasant if the table is already large!

Comment: What should I do instead? Make the table with columns to store the types of measurements that I expect to have in the future and just for now put in them NULL?

Comment: No. I'd make one table for each measurement "type". So, one for Temp, one for Humidity ... and so on.

Comment: No. Think "Foreign Keys". You have a Table for a Measurement, which generates a unique ID for each mesurement. Then you enter the data in the according tables - if the sensor only takes temp then only there. So later, when you query, you'll do a join over the measurement tables with that id. Where there's no value, a null will be presented in the view.

Comment: That way you can easily chose Measurement types, reducing the data enormously if you for example want to make a heatmap over temperature. You just won't fetch all the other measurement types.

Comment: Same for static/dynamic: You just save positiondata for dynamic sensors. So if you want to query only static sensors, you will write a select that joins in a way where all entries with an entry in posiiton table are filtered out. And the other way round: only dynamic sensors: join so that you only get entries with position data present.

Comment: https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/third-normal-form-3nf.php - It is not always practical to implement 3rd normal form strictly. But if in doubt it is a good rule of thumb to work towards a 3rd normal form.

Comment: How about not having 'am_measurements' table and just put: id_sensor, time, temp_value in the corresponding type of measurement table(s)? We'll have unique time for every id_sensor. We can save some space because in this case there would be no need to store id_measurement which should be BIGINT because of the great amount of sensors.